# Django CSRF validation fails on POST requests : referer checking failed - no Referer

Tags: django, python-requests, csrf

My Django website is in HTTPS. When I am trying to POST data to the website from a script I get this error : "referer checking failed - no Referer". It seems to be a CSRF issue but I do not know how to solve it.

Example :

```
import requests
r = requests.post('https://mywebsite/mypage', data = {'key':'value'})
print r.text
```

gives me this output :

```
[...]

<p>Reason given for failure:</p>
<pre>
Referer checking failed - no Referer.
</pre>

<p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when
<a
href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/">Django's
CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to
ensure:</p>

<ul>
<li>Your browser is accepting cookies.</li>

<li>The view function passes a <code>request</code> to the template's <a
href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render"><code>render</code></a>
method.</li>

<li>In the template, there is a <code>{% csrf_token
%}</code> template tag inside each POST form that
targets an internal URL.</li>

<li>If you are not using <code>CsrfViewMiddleware</code>, then you must use
<code>csrf_protect</code> on any views that use the <code>csrf_token</code>
template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.</li>

</ul>

[...]
```

Do I need to pass a referer to my headers before sending the POST data - which would not be convenient ? Or should I disable CSRF for this page ?

Thanks

Comment: I am also trouble with this issue.Any answer Julien Salinas?

Comment: @neelima you need to disable CSRF checking in your view. Use the `@csrf_exempt` decorator: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, This is the purpose of CSRF, to avoid posting data from unknown strange sources. You need csrf token to post this which django generates dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Django might fix the missing Referer error.

As of Django 4.0 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf)), the backend will first check the `Origin` header before falling back to the `Referer` header ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#how-it-works)):

> 4. `CsrfViewMiddleware` verifies the Origin header, if provided by the browser, against the current host and the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` setting. This provides protection against cross-subdomain attacks.
> 5. In addition, for HTTPS requests, if the `Origin` header isn’t provided, `CsrfViewMiddleware` performs strict referer checking. This means that even if a subdomain can set or modify cookies on your domain, it can’t force a user to post to your application since that request won’t come from your own exact domain.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have a reverse proxy running, for example an nginx `proxy_pass` to `127.0.0.1:8000`?

In this case, Django expects the Cross-Site Forgery Protection tokens to match hostname `127.0.0.1`, but they will be coming from a normal domain (for example `example.com`).

| Expected Source | Actual Source |
| --- | --- |
| http://127.0.0.1 | https://example.com |

HTTP reverse proxy (`example.com:80` -> `localhost:3000`) is a common way to use [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) with NodeJS applications, but it doesn't work well with Django

| Client-Facing URL | Server Proxy URL |
| --- | --- |
| https://example.com | http://127.0.0.1:3000 |

It is better to run Django through a Unix socket rather than a port (`example.com:80` -> `<socket>`). You can do this with [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/):

| Client-Facing URL | Server Proxy URL |
| --- | --- |
| https://example.com | unix:/run/example.com.sock |

Here's how to do this with Django, Gunicorn, and nginx:

Let's say you've got a Django project root, which contains a system folder (the one where `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` are):

```
export DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH=/path/to/django/root
export DJANGO_SETTING_FOLDER=system
```

First, make sure you have Gunicorn installed and that you are using a virtual environment:

```
cd $DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH
source .venv/bin/activate  # <- Use a virtual environment
pip3 install gunicorn  # <- install Gunicorn in the venv
```

Run Gunicorn. This will start the Django project similar to running `python3 manage.py runserver`, except that you can listen for requests on a Unix socket:

```
$DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH/.venv/bin/gunicorn  \
    --workers=3 \
    --access-logfile - \
    --bind unix:/run/example.com.sock \  # <- Socket
    --chdir=$DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH/ \
    $DJANGO_SETTING_FOLDER.wsgi:application
```

Then create an HTTP proxy using nginx that passes HTTP requests from clients through the gunicon-created socket:

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;

    # serve static files directly through nginx
    location /static/ {
        autoindex off;
        root /path/to/django/root;
    }

    # serve user-uploaded files directly through nginx
    location /media/ {
        autoindex off;
        root  /path/to/django/root;
    } 

    # You can do fun stuff like aliasing files from other folders
    location /robots.txt {
        alias /path/to/django/root/static/robots.txt;
    }

    # here is the proxy magic
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/example.com.sock;  # <- the socket!
    }
}
```

Make sure to restart nginx:

```
sudo service restart nginx
```

After all this, your csrf tokens should match the domain name of your site and you'll be able to log in and submit forms.